# Loading UI elements on user command

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Right now I have a specific group of UI elements(Spinners, edit-boxes, buttons, etc.) which I want to be in the program's UI multiple times. Specifically one copy when the program first loads up and new copies are 'created' and show up in the UI due to user interaction(such as a button press event). I'm aware of using XML to define a specific UI groups but I'm not sure how to properly set up having those groups appear in the UI at the start of the program and by user command within the Java code.

Comment: so you wanna know how to set UI elements programatically?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good idea implements it group of components as a View subclass, this way you view going to comport as a stand-alone component and ready to re-use.

You can still make the layout.xml to it view, inflate it into the onCreate and assign the behaviour of actions in the components of this group.